# How to set the same value on x axis and name a set of subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a subplot in matplotlib, and I would like to set the same value of x axis on all subplot i.e., from 0 to 20. Also Want to rename each subplot separately or add a legend to clarify each subplot for the reader.

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import itertools
 x =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 y =[2, 3, 3, 2, 3] 

 a =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 b =[2, 1, 0, 1, 0] 

 c =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 d =[2, 2, 4, 4, 1] 

 e =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 f =[2, 2, 8, 8, 2] 

 g =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 h =[2.5, 3, 4, 5, 5] 

 i =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 j =[4, 5, 5.5, 9, 0] 

 k =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 l =[10, 10, 10, 10, 10] 

 m =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
 n =[15, 16, 17, 18, 16] 

 fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2) 

 axes[0, 0].plot(x, y, 'b--o') 
 axes[0, 1].plot(a, b, 'b--o') 
 axes[1, 0].plot(c, d, 'r--o') 
 axes[1, 1].plot(e, f, 'r--o') 
 axes[2, 0].plot(g, h, 'g--o') 
 axes[2, 1].plot(i, j, 'g--o') 
 axes[3, 0].plot(k, l, 'm--o')  
 axes[3, 1].plot(m, n, 'm--o') 

 fig.tight_layout() 

 plt.savefig('pq.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

 plt.show()`
```

The result is: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.setp` to set the same x/y limits to all axes:

```
plt.setp(axes, ylim=(0, 20))
```

---

You can use the `label` parameter to name your plots:

```
axes[0, 0].plot(x, y, 'b--o', label='x-y plot')
```

---

You can use `figure.legend` (or `axis.legend`) to plot a legend on the figure (or a legend on each subplot):

```
# one legend on the figure
fig.legend()
```

Or:

```
# one legend on subplot[0, 0]
axes[0, 0].legend()
```

Comment: Thanks @hoomant for your help. The "plt.setp(axes, ylim=(0, 20))" works well, but for adding a name in each sub plot doesn't work. Also if possible I would like to add a name at the end of each 4 sub plot, e.g., 4 subplots right with "Account1" and the 4 subplots left with "Account2". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can visit https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/figlegend_demo.html and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html for more information.